# c# add tag to ListBox item

Tags: c#, listbox

In my application there is a listbox which is being filled dynamically.

Each item needs to have a click event, so it will open a component belonging by this item.

Thereby I need to add a tag on each item, so I can get this tag within the event method.

Listbox:

```
var lb_Volunteers_From_Question = new ListBox();
foreach (var volunteer in volunteers)
{
    lb_Volunteers_From_Question.Items.Add(volunteer.Name);
    {
        // set tag
        Tag = volunteer;
    };

    // set event
    lb_Volunteers_From_Question.Click += new EventHandler(ShowVolunteerProfile);
}

// listbox settings
```

Event method

```
public void ShowVolunteerProfile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get volunteer out of tag
    var item = sender as ListBox;
    var tagQuestionDetail = (TagQuestionDetail)item.Tag;


    // Show volunteer profile info
    // code                     
}
```

But this is not working out for me. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

here:

```
public void ShowVolunteerProfile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get volunteer out of tag
    var item = sender as ListBox;
    var tagQuestionDetail = (TagQuestionDetail)item.SelectedItem.Tag;


    // Show volunteer profile info
    // code                     
}
```

Comment: item.SelectedItem.Tag is no possibility. Only: ToString, Equals, GetHashCode and GetType :(

Comment: @JimVercoelen is this WinForms or WPF?